# Specific names after logrotate

Tags: logrotate

I'd like logrotate to create files which have nice names. Is there some way to force some pattern for the names after rotation? I'd like to create a `service-{year}-{month}-{day}-{hour}` format and rotate hourly.

It seems I'm running a version with `dateext`, but without `dateformat`. I'd like to use this logging way anyways.

Answer (score 10):

logrotate configuration file:

```
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
```

Out:

```
atop.log-2010-09-30-1285850549
```

hour is not supported. You can use the postrotate to rename.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use the debian stable version, so dateext is supported, but dateformat isn't... is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Just what I needed!

Comment: How can I get the export file name in postrotate?